# How to load custom resources (.rc) in vc++ as a string?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

How can I load a custom resource (.rc) from a .dll. I have tried using `LoadResource` and `FindResource` but they don't work. I have also attempted to try using Microsoft's documentation but it is very confusing.

I created the resource (.rc) in visual studios by adding a new item in my .dll project and then imported a .txt file and chose the resource type to be "Text".

[Resource Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFyzK.png)

Then I tried loading it using the code:

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HINST_THISCOMPONENT ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)

LoadResource(HINST_THISCOMPONENT, FindResource(HINST_THISCOMPONENT, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXT1), LoadStringA(Text)));
```

In summary, I have a custom resource in a .dll which I would like to have as a string in my executable.

Comment: I think a bit more detail is required. A custom resource loaded as a string? Or a string resource? Maybe show us some code of your attempts.

Comment: I am following https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/140c5e66-53d2-4e70-808f-ef7a8df1f58b/embedding-bitmap-images-in-exe-and-dll-native-c-amp-community-ed?forum=vcgeneral. Ignore the last step.

Comment: `LoadStringA(Text)` for the last parameter of `FindResource` doesn't make sense.  Show the line in the .rc file that defines `IDR_TEXT1` resource.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not really sure what to put in the last parameter but I would be very grateful if you could explain what the last parameter of `FindResource` takes in.

Comment: [A user-defined resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/user-defined-resource) looks like this in .rc file: `Name Type FileName`. The two last parameters of `FindResource` are `"Name"` and `"Type"` (if either of those was a numeric constant, then substitute `MAKEINTRESOURCE(Name)` or `MAKEINTRESOURCE(Type)`)